# node express sending string as html is converting single quotes into double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, express

i'm trying to send this string as html. The string is stored in a `var`, and is sent using `res.send(respuesta);`

```
<div data-nanogallery2='{
        "itemsBaseURL": "http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
        "thumbnailWidth": "auto",
        "thumbnailBorderVertical": 0,
        "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 0,
        "colorScheme": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
          }
        },
        "thumbnailDisplayTransition": "flipDown",
        "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 750,
        "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 250,
        "thumbnailLabel": {
          "display": false
        },
        "thumbnailHoverEffect2": "toolsAppear|scale120",
        "galleryDisplayMode": "pagination",
        "galleryPaginationMode": "numbers",
        "thumbnailAlignment": "center"
      }'>
      <a href="berlin1.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin1t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 1</a>
      <a href="berlin2.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin2t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 2</a>
      <a href="berlin3.jpg" data-ngthumb="berlin3t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">Berlin 3</a>

    </div>
```

The problem is that somehow all the `'` are automatically converted into `"`, so that is messing my client-side markup.

Is there any way to maintain the `'` ?

EDIT:
I'm trying to generate this section of HTML dynamically. It is used by a gallery library. That `const` is always the same, then i generate the links with the picture info and add them to the string, then send the string `respuesta` to the client via `ajax` to append it.

```
// GETS
router.get('/bodas', function (req, res) {
    Foto.find({ tipo: 'bodas' }).lean().exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var respuesta = generateBodasHTML(data);
        res.send(respuesta);
    });
});
function generateBodasHTML(data) {
    var respuesta = cuerpoGaleria0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        respuesta += '<a href="' + data[i].foto_name + '" data-ngthumb="' + data[i].thumb_name + '" data-ngdesc="">' + data[i].name + '</a>';
    }
    respuesta += "</div></div>";
    return respuesta;
}
const cuerpoGaleria0 = `<div class="page_wrapper_home"><div data-nanogallery2='{"itemsBaseURL": "../assets/galeria/", "thumbnailWidth": "auto", "thumbnailBorderVertical": 0, "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 0, "colorScheme": { "thumbnail": { "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)" } }, "thumbnailDisplayTransition": "flipDown", "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 750, "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 250, "thumbnailLabel": { "display": false }, "thumbnailHoverEffect2": "toolsAppear|scale120", "galleryDisplayMode": "pagination", "galleryPaginationMode": "numbers", "thumbnailAlignment": "center"}'>`;
```

and this is the `ajax call`:

```
function getContentAjax(pagina) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/' + pagina
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#contenido').append(result);
            toggleSliders();

            if (pagina === 'inicio') {
                triggerHomeAnimations();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the backtick **`**

```
`{
    "itemsBaseURL": "http://nanogallery2.nanostudio.org/samples/",
    "thumbnailWidth": "auto",
    "thumbnailBorderVertical": 0,
    "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 0,
    "colorScheme": {
      "thumbnail": {
        "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      }
    },
    "thumbnailDisplayTransition": "flipDown",
    "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 750,
    "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 250,
    "thumbnailLabel": {
      "display": false
    },
    "thumbnailHoverEffect2": "toolsAppear|scale120",
    "galleryDisplayMode": "pagination",
    "galleryPaginationMode": "numbers",
    "thumbnailAlignment": "center"
  }`>
```

Comment: it keeps behaving wierdly. it's adding an extra `"`.... `<div data-nanogallery2="`{` here for example...

Answer (score 0):

Update: There still appears to be no problem with Express as asked in the question title.

Perhaps the AJAX request is causing a problem but the post contains no debugging information generated about the response received in the browser.

If you run this test server locally in nodejs:

**Express Server**

```
var app = express();
app.get("/bodas", function( req, res, next) {
    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>\n\n';

    var data = [
        {foto_name: "foto_name1", thumb_name: "thumb_name1", name: "name1"},
        {foto_name: "foto_name2", thumb_name: "thumb_name2", name: "name2"},
        {foto_name: "foto_name3", thumb_name: "thumb_name3 ", name: "name3"}
    ];
    var respuesta = generateBodasHTML(data);

    res.send(html + respuesta + '\n\n</body></html>');
});
function generateBodasHTML(data) {
    var respuesta = cuerpoGaleria0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        respuesta += '<a href="' + data[i].foto_name + '" data-ngthumb="' + data[i].thumb_name + '" data-ngdesc="">' + data[i].name + '</a></br>';
    }
    respuesta += "</div></div>";
    return respuesta;
}
const cuerpoGaleria0 = `<div class="page_wrapper_home"><div data-nanogallery2='{"itemsBaseURL": "../assets/galeria/", "thumbnailWidth": "auto", "thumbnailBorderVertical": 0, "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 0, "colorScheme": { "thumbnail": { "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)" } }, "thumbnailDisplayTransition": "flipDown", "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 750, "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 250, "thumbnailLabel": { "display": false }, "thumbnailHoverEffect2": "toolsAppear|scale120", "galleryDisplayMode": "pagination", "galleryPaginationMode": "numbers", "thumbnailAlignment": "center"}'>`;

var server = app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log("testexpress listening on local host port 80");
});
```

and look at the page source of the page sent using the URL:

```
http://localhost/bodas
```

you can see the single quote marks are preserved and the `data-nanogallery2` attribute is syntactically valid.

Please read "how to create a complete and verifiable example" in the help center of your preferred language site (e.g. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , https://en.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ). Including test data increases your chance of getting useful answers.